# Im getting an unnamed state after onChange in input type file - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-upload, react-state, input-type-file

I'm using input type file to upload images to strapi.io. I noticed that in the state on the react dev tools it generate a unnamed state seen in the image below.

[image]

**state**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      address: '',
      email:'',
      city: '',
      country: '',
      zipcode: '',
      gcash_number: '',
      paypal_email: '',
      error: '', 
      bank_account: '',
      bank_name: ''
    }
    this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this)
  }
```

**JSX**

```
<div className='col-sm-auto'>
  <label htmlFor='avatar' >Avatar</label>
   <input type='file' className="form-control-file form-control-sm" onChange={this.handleOnChange('avatar')}/>            
</div>
```

**handleOnChange function**

```
handleOnChange = input => (event) => {
    if (event.target.type === 'file') {
      this.setState({avatars: event.target.files[0]})
    }
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  }
```

can some explain to me how this happened? and how to put a state name on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
});
```

`name` is undefined

Try

```
<input name="myInputName" type='file' className="form-control-file form-control-sm" onChange={this.handleOnChange('avatar')}/>
```

Comment: ohh so the name attribute of the input tag will be the name of the state thanks

Comment: @carljustineoyales yes, if that is your use case. Or, you can define a concrete name for your state on the state definition.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to define an id for the input element:

```
<input id="InputID" type='file' className="form-control-file form-control-sm" onChange={this.handleOnChange('avatar')}/>
```

**Because you used htmlFor in the label tag**
 And try the following code :

```
this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value });
```